# Need help with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$text = '<p width="50px;" style="padding:0px;"><strong style="padding:0;margin:0;">hello</strong></p><table style="text-align:center"></table>';

$text_2 = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $text);
```

**OUTPUT(i have given the html format here):**

```
<p>
<strong>hello</strong>
</p>
<table></table>
```

My problem is all attributes must be removed but not the attributes belongs to table. That is i am expecting the out put exactly like below(**HTML FORMAT**):

```
<p>
<strong>hello</strong>
</p>
<table style="text-align:center"></table>
```

What should i need to modify in the above regular expression to achieve it..

Any help will be thankful and grateful....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: how can I remove attributes from an html tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/php-how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close with your current reg-ex. You need to do a check (think it is a negative look-ahead in this case?)

`<(?!table)([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>`

What that first bit of reg-ex is doing is checking that it does not start with 'table', then it is your regex.

Comment: Thanks Dickie... You make me form :-( to :-) by ur answer.... Thanks pal... I have one more small doubt. If i need to add two or more tags like table in the NOT condition how should i do?...

Comment: you can add your own tags to the look-ahead, for example `(?!table|div|othertag)`

Comment: thanks your very much for your immediate response Dickie.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using regex, because you really souldn't use regex to work on xml/html structures, try:

```
<?php
$text = '<p width="50px;" style="padding:0px;"><strong style="padding:0;margin:0;">hello</strong></p><table style="text-align:center"></table>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHtml($text);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[not(name()="table")]/@*') as $attrNode) {
    $attrNode->ownerElement->removeAttributeNode($attrNode);
}

$output = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//body/*') as $childNode) {
    $output[] = $dom->saveXml($childNode, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}

echo implode("\n", $output);
```

**Output**:

```
<p>
  <strong>hello</strong>
</p>
<table style="text-align:center"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice "souldn't use regex to work on xml/html structures". But in my case it is just to view the content in PDF. That's y i gone for it...

Answer (score 0):

Bit of hacky solution, but works .
Try disabling TABLE tags for a while in your code, and enable them again.
It would work.

see : http://codepad.org/nevLWMq8

```
<?php

$text = '<p width="50px;" style="padding:0px;"><strong style="padding:0;margin:0;">hello</strong></p><table style="text-align:center"></table>';

/* temporary change table tags with something not occuring in your HTML  */
$textTemp = str_replace(array("<table","/table>"),array('###','+++'),$text);


$text_2 = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $textTemp);



echo "\n\n";
 /* restore back the table tags */

$finalText =  str_replace(array("###","+++"),array("<table","/table>"),$text_2);
echo $finalText ;

?>
```