# What is the function function in WordPress that formats HTML for comments?

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress there is a function of some sort that will strip html tags but allow certain tags and certain attributes. I was able to find how to change the allowed tags and attributes but no luck trying to find the actual "strip_tags" function that i could use elsewhere in my theme that abides by the set parameters. It would be extremely useful to know this function name.

Comment: `strip_tags` is a PHP function.

Comment: You mean a function that isn't [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: yes. If you look at wordpress comments, the default form shows allowed tags - which works with strip_tags but also it has allowed attributes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: how can I remove attributes from an html tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/php-how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Comment: Probably get better traction on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean [wp_kses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses)?

Comment: Nice find! i think that's it.

Comment: right, wordpress uses this function to make sure the comments are safe.. the build in strip_tags function won't do the trick for several reason like the fact that if you allow some tags you can't block the attributes.. more info on why strip_tags is not used for this you can find here http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/nj5t0/what_everyone_should_know_about_strip_tags/