# How to strip specific tags and specific attributes from a string?

Tags: php, html, whitelist

Here's the deal, I'm making a project to help teach HTML to people. Naturally, I'm afraid of that Scumbag Steve (see figure 1).

So I wanted to block **ALL** HTML tags, **except** those approved on a very specific ***whitelist***.

Out of those approved HTML tags, I want to remove harmful **attributes** as well. Such as `onload` and `onmouseover`. Also, **according to a *whitelist***.

I've thought of regex, but I'm pretty sure it's evil and not very helpful for the job.

Could anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

---

Fig 1.

[image: Scumbag Steve]

Comment: Actually using regular expressions is the way to go. At least, I would strongly recommend it. They'll give you great flexibility and controller over the strings you're parsing.

Comment: the way to go http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @Deleteman: Yes, but I've stated I want a **whitelist**, not a **blacklist**, meaning, everything's blocked, except some specific tags. I don't know how to handle that with RegEx (it would be great if you could throw a small-scale example)

Comment: @Truth I could, but that htmlpurifier.org posted by aSeptik seems to be your solution :)

Comment: @aSeptik: The following: http://tinyurl.com/c8qwqld should have not removed the input attribute, why did it?

Comment: @Truth: i can't test it now, but for sure you should test it on your own, it have lots of powerfull features. Most probably some tags are not allowed on demo mode. as soon as possible i will put a responce \w demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/how-to-strip-specific-tags-and-specific-attributes-from-a-string/

```
require_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

 // this one is needed cause otherwise stuff 
 // considered harmful like input's will automatically be deleted
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);

// this line say that only input, p, div will be accepted
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', 'input,p,div');

// set attributes for each tag
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', 'input.type,input.name,p.id,div.style');

// more extensive way of manage attribute and elements... see the docs
// http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);

$def->addAttribute('input', 'type', 'Enum#text');
$def->addAttribute('input', 'name', 'Text');

// call...
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

// display...
$html = $purifier->purify($raw_html);
```

> - **NOTE:** as you asked this code will run as a Whitelist, only input, p and div are accepted and only certains attributes are accepted.

Comment: I think you can do some harm using style attributes in IE. At least in a normal stylesheet you can reference javascript-based behaviour files.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: yep, but don't warry HTMLPurifier automatically strip out any reference to .htc files! ;-)

Comment: Perfect answer! Documented and everything! +1+accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zend framework 2 strip tags](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Filter.StripTags.html). An example below to accept ul, li, p... and img (only with src attribute) and links (with only href atttribute). Everything else will be stripped. If I'm not wrong zf1 does the same thing

```
     $filter = new \Zend\Filter\StripTags(array(
        'allowTags'   => array(
            'ul'=>array(), 
            'li'=>array(), 
            'p'=>array(), 
            'br'=>array(), 
            'img'=>array('src'), 
            'a'=>array('href')
         ),
        'allowAttribs'  => array(),
        'allowComments' => false)
    );

    $value = $filter->filter($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

For tags you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

For attributes, refer to [How can I remove attributes from an html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Comment: I don't want all the attributes (as some are needed for learning), I want specific ones to be allowed, this doesn't seem to be addressed in your second link.