# Removing tag attributes with regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to remove all attributes from `<a>` tag except `href="/index.php..."` ? and add a custom class to it ?

So this:

```
<a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&Itemid=105&lang=en" style="float:right;">content</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&Itemid=105&lang=en" class="custom">content</a>
```

i cant manage the preg_replace to work it: `

```
<?php
    $text = '<a href="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&Itemid=105&lang=en" class="custom">content</a>';
    echo preg_replace("/<a([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:[^>]*(\shref=['\"][^'\"]['\"]))?>/i", '<$1$2$3>', $text);
?>
```

Comment: Sure sounds like an easier job with a parser.

Comment: i tried it if you are talking about html parser, but i can't manage it

Comment: Possible duplicate with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm talking about. Perhaps you could post what you tried and we could help with that?

Comment: @Wiseguy - i tried that: `$doc = new DOMDocument();$doc->loadHTML($data->cart_show);`, but i see the answer already that it mine code wasn't finished. thanks for pointing me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMDocument` is better, but with regex

```
preg_replace("/<a [^>]*?(href=[^ >]+)[^>]*>/i", '<a $1 class="custom">', $text);
```

Assumes no space in `href` and no `>` in attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DomDocument`:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&Itemid=105&lang=en" style="float:right;">content</a>');
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$href = $items->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
$value = $items->item(0)->nodeValue;
libxml_clear_errors();
echo '<a href="'.$href.'" class="custom">'.$value.'</a>';
```

Comment: i tried that one already, but without `libxml_` (didnt know about them) and it didn't worked.