# Remove all attributes from PHP string but keep basic markdown tags

Tags: php, regex, xpath, domdocument, strip-tags

Lets say i have a string containing:

```
"Lorem ipsum <br> 
<img alt="sometext" onload="XSS" src="http://adomain.com/image.jpg"/><br>
<a class="imagehref" href="#"><img src="imagelink"><a/>
<p class="bold">Bold title tag</b>"
```

What i want to do is remove any attributes and and just be left with the bare minimum.

So i would like that string to change to:

```
"Lorem ipsum <br> 
<img src="http://adomain.com/image.jpg"/><br>
<a href="#"><img src="imagelink"><a/>
<p>Bold title tag</b>"
```

The idea is for users to copy and paste forum posts into my website. I need to then save this data as basic html markdown with no extra attributes.

I have look at using regular expressions, but i could be here for hours writing different variations to try and catch all attributes etc. But that is not stable / efficient enough for what i want.

The issue is that many different forums use their own way of marking up images so i can write fixed rules. There are some that use '' / "" and some that self close the tags etc.

I there a way to what i need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag

Comment: Do you have a full whitelist for the attributes you want to keep?

Comment: I think that the simpliest way is to parse your document node by node and to rebuild a new document only with attributes you need.