# php remove all attributes from a tag

Tags: php, regex

Here is my code:

```
$content2= preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $content1);
```

This code removes all attributes from all tags in my website, but what I want is to only remove attributes from the `form` tag. This is what I have tried:

```
$content2 = preg_replace("/<form([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $content1);
```

and

```
$content2 = preg_replace("/<(form[a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $content1);
```

Comment: what is $content1 and what it should be?

Comment: $content1 is just the source code of my whole website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
<?php
$content1 = '<form method="post">test</form><form>2</form><form action=\'test\' method="post" type="blah"><img><b>bold</b></form>';
$content2 = preg_replace("~<form\s+.*?>~i",'<form>', $content1);
echo $content2;
```

Output:

```
<form>test</form><form>2</form><form><img><b>bold</b></form>
```

Explanation and demo: https://regex101.com/r/oA1fV8/1

The `\s+` is requiring whitespace after the opening `form` tag if we have that we presume there is an attribute after so we use `.*?` which takes everything until the next `>`. We don't need capture groups because the only thing you want is an empty `form` element, right?

Comment: My example only has 3 parameters for the `preg_replace`. What is the code you are running?

Comment: No problem. Also keep in mind this requires valid HTML/XML this can get messy if a `form` is missing a `>`. You may want to consider an HTML/XML parser in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from a related question:

```
<?php
function stripArgumentFromTags( $htmlString ) {
    $regEx = '/([^<]*<\s*[a-z](?:[0-9]|[a-z]{0,9}))(?:(?:\s*[a-z\-]{2,14}\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'))*)(\s*\/?>[^<]*)/i'; // match any start tag

    $chunks = preg_split($regEx, $htmlString, -1,  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $chunkCount = count($chunks);

    $strippedString = '';
    for ($n = 1; $n < $chunkCount; $n++) {
        $strippedString .= $chunks[$n];
    }

    return $strippedString;
}
?>
```

Then use call call it like this

```
$strippedTag = stripArgumentFromTags($initialTag);
```

[Related question with more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag)

Comment: it didn't work for me how can I remove attributes from <form> tag ?